# Retrieve objects from Parse and put them in an array

Tags: arrays, parse-platform

I have a class "Object" on Parse which contains a column with int values named "Score". I want to put all those values (using a Parse Query) inside an array which is going to be used in my project. So, how can I retrieve those int values from Parse and put them in an array? The docs in the website seem to give examples and lessons only on retrieving object with known ID (which is useless to me).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS SDK

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Object"); // Object is classname
query.limit(1000);
query.descending("createdAt");
query.exists("Score");
query.find().then(function(results) {
     // results is the list where Score exist
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I put the results in an array and then for example make the System count these results and show me how many of them there are by printing the count in a textview? (Talking about Android Studio)

Comment: Do you want android sdk or cloud sdk?